# Keys are showing up undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the keys and values of a JavaScript object to fill in attributes and text for a drop down menu I am creating dynamically.

Here is the relevant code

HTML:

```
<div>
  <select id="docs">
    <option>- Choose a document to preview -</option>
    <option id="specEd" class="eng kor viet esp chin">Special Education Programs</option>
    <option id="parRight" class="eng kor esp">Special Ed. Parents Rights</option>
    <option id="cac" class="eng esp">CAC Brochure</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="langSelectBox" class="clearfix">
  <h3>Select a Language</h3>
  <select class="language" style="display:none;">
  </select>
  <div id="brochure">
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var map = {
    "eng" : "English",
    "esp" : "Español",
    "kor" : "한국어",
    "viet" : "Tiếng Việt",
    "chin" : "中文"
  }

  $brochureSelect.on("change", function() {

    $(".language").html("");
    var selected = $("option:selected", this).attr("class");
    var arr = selected.split(" ");

    $.each(map, function(k, v) {
      $(".language").append("<option id="+map[v]+">"+map[k]+"</option>");
    });
  });
});
```

My trouble occurs when I am interacting with `map`. When this runs I have my drop down menus, but the value of all their id attributes is `undefined`. In other words the `k` in the function is returning `undefined`.  I read the documentation of `$.each` and this should be working, yet the only variable that works is the `k`. I've tried defining the variable `map` outside the function, taking away quotation marks, and changing double quotes to single quotes.

Here is what it looks like:

```
<select class="language">
  <option id="undefined">English</option>
  <option id="undefined">Español</option>
  <option id="undefined">한국어</option>
  <option id="undefined">Tiếng Việt</option>
  <option id="undefined">中文</option>
</select>
```

I'd like this:

```
<select class="language">
  <option id="eng">English</option>
  <option id="esp">Español</option>
  <option id="kor">한국어</option>
  <option id="viet">Tiếng Việt</option>
  <option id="chin">中文</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is $brochureSelect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the key and value instead of map[k] & map[v]

```
$.each(map, function(k, v){
  console.log(k)
  $(".language").append("<option id="+k+">"+v+"</option>");
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function:

```
k = key (e.g. "eng")

v = value (e.g. "English")
```

So your each function should look like:

```
$.each(map, function(k, v){

  $(".language").append("<option id="+ k +">"+ v +"</option>");

});
```